# How to implement parameters with unknown types and unknown number in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reduce

I'd like to implement a function in Scala/Spark, which can take multiple reducers/aggregators and execute them in a single pass. So basically I give the reduce functions and initial values and it should create a compound reduce operation in a single pass.

Here is what the logic would look like in Python

```
from functools import reduce

def reduce_at_once(data, reducer_funcs_inits):
    reducer_funcs, inits = zip(*reducer_funcs_inits)

    complete_reducer_func = lambda acc, y: tuple(rf(a_x, y) for a_x, rf in zip(acc, reducer_funcs))

    return list(reduce(complete_reducer_func, data, inits))

data = list(range(1, 20))
reducer_funcs_inits = [(lambda acc, y: acc + y, 0), # sum
                       (lambda acc, y: acc * y, 1)  # product
                       ]
print(list(reduce_at_once(data, reducer_funcs_inits)))
# [190, 121645100408832000]
```

How can I do something like this in Scala (Spark)? The issue seems that I have a list whose length I only know when calling, but also the elements of the list may have different types (reduce initial accumulator) depending on which reducer I want to include (not necessarily only numbers like here).

Comment: You should add the `python` label also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use

```
def reduce_at_once(data: Any, reducer_funcs_inits: Any*)
```

but this is very rarely what you want. In particular, here you actually need

```
case class ReducerInit[A, B](f: (B, A) => B, init: B)

def reduce_at_once[A](data: Seq[A], rfis: ReducerInit[A, _]*): Seq[_]
```

Unfortunately, implementing `reduce_at_once` is going to be pretty ugly:

```
def reduce_at_once[A](data: Seq[A], rfis: ReducerInit[A, _]*): Seq[_] = {
  val rfs = rfis.map(_.f.asInstanceOf[(Any, A) => Any])
  val inits = rfis.map(_.init.asInstanceOf[Any])

  val crf = (acc: Seq[Any], y: A) => acc.zip(rfs).map { case (a_x, rf) => rf(a_x, y) }

  data.foldLeft(inits)(crf)
}
```

To check:

```
val data = 1 to 20

val rf1 = ReducerInit[Int, Int](_ + _, 0)
val rf2 = ReducerInit[Int, Int](_ * _, 1)

println(reduce_at_once(data, rf1, rf2))
```

[gives](http://scastie.org/13589) `ArrayBuffer(210, -2102132736)` (note overflow).